# Django: Better way to aggregate QuerySet results

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following code snippet. I first tried to get the count for male / female directly as annotation but I didn't manage to get these. Therefore I wrote the following for loop. However, it still feels that this solution is not as good as it could be. Do you have any other idea how to write better code here?

```
genders = self.get_answers(self.get_super_guests(), QuestionFocus.GENDER)
# >>> <QuerySet [Answer: Male, Answer: Female, Answer: Male]>
male = female = 0
for gender in genders:
    if gender.answer == "Male":
        male += 1
    elif gender.answer == "Female":
        female += 1

print("Gender distribution is Male", male, "Female: ", female)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can annotate the values of the queryset with the number of items, like:

```
result = genders.values('answer').annotate(
    number=Count('answer')
).order_by('answer')
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` that looks like:

```
<QuerySet [
    { 'answer': 'Male', 'number': 14},
    { 'answer': 'Female', 'number': 25}
]>
```

Comment: Amazing, that actually works. I didn't use the `order_by` when I tried it, which seems to be necessary. Is there a way to extend this query that I also get the total number of answer. In your example total=39 (14+25). I tried to add `.annotate(number=Count('answer'))` before `.values`, but that's just ignored.

Comment: @JoeyCoder: some databases have a `ROLLUP` clause, but to the best of my knowledge, that is not yet part of the Django ORM. I think you thus will need to calculate the total yourself (sorry :s).

Comment: Ok, no problem. Then I will hand that task to Python. Thank you Willem!

Answer (score 1):

```
# if your model name is QuestionFocus, then your query should be like this

QuestionFocus.objects.values('answer').annotate(number=Count('answer'))
```